# Is it known whether for some $k > 1$, there are infinitely many primes of the form $p = \sum_{n=j}^m n^k$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

So I know the results about arithmetic progressions and primes, but I was curious about other progressions and naturally occurring collections of natural numbers. If we consider  $\sum_{n=j}^m n^k$ for arbitrary $j,m > 0$ and some $k > 1$, is it known which such collections have infinitely many primes (for a fixed $k$)? Even partial answers, i.e. answers for some particular values of $k$ would be interesting. I tried factoring the polynomial expressions for such summations to get a possible answer but to no avail...

UPDATE: I just realized that for $k = 3$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^m n^3$ is a square so for any $j,m$ the expression $\sum_{n=j}^m n^3$ is a non-trivial difference of squares and hence cannot be prime. A comment also pointed out $k=1$ is trivial. Other values of $k$ remain elusive...

Comment: Trivially, for $k= 1$ all primes $p$ can be represented choosing $j = m = p$.

Comment: @Dominik whoops yeah, I should have been more careful about corner cases. Thanks, i'll revise.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I could only determine for $k = 2$ that it's composite for infinitely many non-trivial cases (i.e. $m > j+1$). If you have time, could you elaborate?

Comment: For $k=2$ the problem boils down to figuring when $\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}-\frac{j(j+1)(2j+1)}{6}$ is prime. Doesn't seem to be easy, but might be doable.

Comment: Relevant to the case where $j$ is fixed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Partial Answer**

For $k=2m+1$ odd and $j <m$ if we denote by

$$S=\sum_{n=j}^m n^k$$
then 
$$2S= \sum_{n=j}^m n^{2m+1} + (m-j+n)^{2m+1}= \sum_{n=j}^m \left( n + (m+j-n) \right)(n^{2m} + ....)=(m+j)(\mbox{ junk }) $$

[you can make this shorter by observing that $a+b|a^k+b^k$, thus $m+j| n^{2m+1} + (m-j+n)^{2m+1}$ ].

Therefore, $m+j |2S$. As $m+j \neq 1, 2$ and $S$ is prime it follows that $m+j=S$ or $m+j=2S$.

It is trivial to check that for $k \geq 3$ and $j <m$ we have 
$$S=\sum_{n=j}^m n^k \geq m^kj^k >2m+2j > m+j$$

so the above is not possible.

If $j=m$ we have $S=m^k$ is not prime.

This shows that for $k \geq 3$ odd and $1\leq j \leq m$, $$S=\sum_{n=j}^m n^k$$ is **never** prime.

Comment: Wow, nice! I upvoted and if no one can give a substantially more complete answer soon I'll accept this. I had a feeling that the $k = 3$ result that it's never prime probably was indicative of something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

Let $$P_k(m)=\sum_{n=0}^m n^k$$

Then your value is $P_k(m)-P_k(j-1)$.

Now, it is know that $P_k(m)= \frac{Q_k(m)}{(k+1)!}$ for some integer polynomial $Q_k$.

Since $Q_k$ has integer coefficients, $Q_k(m)-Q_k(j-1)$ is always divisible by $m-(j-1)$. So you'd need $$m-(j-1)\mid(k+1)!$$ (It is not possible for $m-(j-1)\geq P(m)-P(j-1)$ except when $k=0$, so if $P_k(m)-P_k(j-1)$ is prime, it is not a divisor of $m-(j-1)$.)

This gives an upper bound for the number of terms that can sum to a prime. For example, $7$ or more consecutive squares cannot add to a prime. Also no four or five consecutive squares. When $k=2$, you can might be able to find two, three or six consecutive squares that add to a prime. A prime $p$ can be written as a sum of $2$ consecutive squares if $2p-1$ is square. I doubt if it is known 
whether there are infinitely many such $p$.

You actually get slightly better denominators in reality - for $k=4$ you must have $m-j+1\mid 30$ and for $k=6$ you must have $m-j+1\mid 42$.

For $k=2, m-(j-1)=3$ there are example like $2^2+3^2+4^2=29$. Again I doubt if it is known whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $3m^2+2$.

For $k=2, m-(j-1)=6$ you are trying to find primes of the form $6 M^2+30 M+55$. This is prime for $184$ values of $M\leq 1000$.

For $k=4$ and $k=6$, you actually get a smaller denominator, $30$ and $42,$ respectively.

More generally, the denominator can be made a divisor of $\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,3,\dots,k+1)$. Usually it is less.

You can quickly see that $m-j+1$ cannot be a multiple of $4$, because then the sum is even. Indeed, $4$ is also never a divisor of the lowest common denominator for $P_k$, I think.

The lowest common denominators are all over the place:

```
  k        Denom
  0            1
  2            6
  4           30
  6           42
  8           90
 10           66
 12         2730
 14           90
 16          510
 18         3990
 20         6930
 22          690
 24        13650
 26          378
 28          870
 30        14322
 32       117810
 34          210
 36      1919190
 38         8190
 40        94710
 42        99330
 44       217350
 46         9870
 48       324870
 50        43758
 52        17490
 54        43890
 56        49590
 58         1770
 60     56786730
 62       270270
 64       364650
 66      5501370
 68        14490
 70        23430
 72   1541109570
 74      8558550
 76        30030
 78        16590
 80     43471890
 82      3259410
 84   3183029850
 86      2612610
 88      5588310
 90   2847714870
 92    191843190
 94       219450
 96     49519470
 98       656370
100      7365930
```

When $k=4$, there are prime values for $d=m-j+1$ for each divisor of $30$. Lots of primes when $d=30$. When $k=6$ the possible values for $d=m-j+1$ are divisors of $42$, in which case, except for $d=1,2$, there is a reasonable number of values.

At this point, the numbers start slowing down my poor code. For $k=8$, 
$$1^8+2^8 (d=2)\\2^8+3^8+4^8(d=3)\\25^8+26^8+27^8+28^8+29^8 (d=5)\\5^8+6^8+7^8+8^8+9^8+10^8 (d=6)\\
5^8+\cdots+14^8(d=10)\\
68^8+\cdots+82^8(d=15)\\
14^8+\cdots+43^8(d=30)
$$ are primes. No $d$ which is a multiple of $9$ will work, since any sum of $9$ consecutive powers of $8$ (or any even number) is divisible by $3$.

Comment: I find it surprising how sometimes for problems about the integers the parity of (one of) the variable makes a huge difference, even if at the first glance it seems irrelevant. The other example I have in mind is $\sum \frac{1}{n^k}$ with $k$ odd or even....

Comment: Since Bernoulli numbers come up in both the formula for $\zeta(2n)$ and $\sum_{m=1}^n m^k$, I wouldn't be surprised there was a relation between these two questions. But I'm not deep enough into this area to argue definitively. @N.S.